Building a Reinforcement Learning Model by combining outputs of many different ML models
Compared to many people, I am an amateur about coding and I need some guidance.
After careful writing and tweaking to build a stock price predictor (hopefull a trading bot after that), I built 3 different ML models: CNN+LSTM, Stacked Autoencoders with LSTM and a Liquid Time Constant model, to employ LNN. I saved their model files and scalers and model weights (for LNN). Got decent MSE, MAE, RMSE and Theil's U (U1) results with them.
Now I want to bring their outputs together in a reinforcement learning model, which will benefit from goal and reward functions. I can imagine that I am about to step onto the hardest part of my journey. My first option is to write a Qlearning Class to operate on Tensorflow (python). Then I switched to using Tensorflow agents to combine and stack different model files. It is very dark in here. Anybody with some guidance?
Currently I am  trying this one:
# Define a custom environment for the stock market data
class StockMarketEnv(suite_gym.GymEnv):
    """Custom environment for our Stock Market Predictor."""
    def __init__(self, data):
        super().__init__(data, max_episode_steps=1000)
        self._data = data  # This should be pre-processed market data

    def observation_spec(self):
        """Returns the observation spec."""
        return self._data.shape[1]  # Number of features

    def action_spec(self):
        """Returns the action spec."""
        return 3  # For example: Buy, Hold, Sell

my second option is to go with OpenAI Gym or some other library. Please help on the optimal method to choose and how to start implementing it.
Thanks a lot in advance
I tried to build a class with Tensorflow, but it is just an initial effort. I do have the model outputs and scalers+weights of my previous models to use as inputs in my upcoming RL model though.

You've made significant progress in building machine learning models for stock price prediction and are now venturing into reinforcement learning (RL) to create a trading bot. Integrating different model outputs into an RL framework can indeed be challenging but also rewarding.You have several options when it comes to RL frameworks. You mentioned TensorFlow and TensorFlow Agents, but OpenAI Gym is also a popular choice.

To create a trading bot, you'll need to design a custom reinforcement learning environment that integrates your stock market prediction models. Here's a suggested approach:
Observation Space: This encompasses the inputs to your machine learning models, such as historical stock prices and technical indicators.
Action Space: Specify the actions available to the agent, such as purchasing stocks, selling stocks, or holding onto current positions.
